# Javascript class with array can't get length

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a custom javascript class that contains an array, when I add a method to return the length, it is always 0. I'm sure its something I'm missing.. any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/ypWsZ/1/

```
function MyObject(){
    this.name='';
}

var selected = (function(){
    var arr = new Array();

    return {
        add : function(s){
            arr.push(s);
        },
        length: function(){
            return arr.length;
        }()
    };
})();

$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj = new MyObject();
    obj.name = 'test';

    selected.add(obj);
    selected.add(obj);
    alert(selected.length);
});
```

Comment: take out the `()` after the `length` anonymous function definition

Comment: I did that orginally but it just returns the javascript code, not the length

Comment: The way this is normally done is that `.length` isn't a method, it's a property. When you call `.add()`, it internally adds `1` to the property. Then, whenever you access `.length`, it should have the current number of items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    length: function(){
        return arr.length;
    }()
```

Typo: length is the result (0) of invoking an anonymous function. Remove the `()` at the end and use:

```
alert(selected.length());
```

Comment: ah duh, that was it.. always forget about parenthesis, thanks